# Output of xgboost() while optimization is not very intuitive

Tags: r, machine-learning, predictive-models, boosting

I am running xgboost() on a data set with a data set with below columns.

```
`data.frame':   24045 obs. of  32 variable
$ LanID                    : Factor w/ 14853 levels "ADV1610403456773583",..: 520 6286 4471 8102 8215 6871 3404 6151 1417 268 ...
 $ Region                   : Factor w/ 4 levels "EAST","NORTH",..: 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 3 3 4 ...
 $ Loan.City                : Factor w/ 7 levels "Bangalore","Chennai",..: 5 7 6 1 1 1 3 1 1 5 ...
 $ Loan.Type                : Factor w/ 6 levels "EMI Free Loan",..: 2 2 1 5 2 5 5 3 6 6 ...
 $ Loan.Scheme              : Factor w/ 4 levels "others","Paytm Term Loan",..: 1 1 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Loan.Status              : Factor w/ 2 levels "active","closed": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Last.EMI                 : num  2512 1479 4500 5875 4992 ...
 $ All.Dues                 : num  2692 1479 0 0 67048 ...
 $ Bullets.Overdue          : num  0 0 30000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Loan.Quality             : Factor w/ 7 levels "Closed","Doubtful",..: 6 6 6 6 7 6 6 6 6 4 ...
 $ Tenure                   : num  8 24 24 23 14 23 24 24 14 8 ...
 $ Gender                   : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Educational.Qualification: Factor w/ 6 levels "graduate","Not Available",..: 2 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ Marital.Status           : Factor w/ 3 levels "married","single",..: 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ Employment.Year          : Factor w/ 4 levels "less-than-2-years",..: 4 3 3 3 1 2 3 1 4 4 ...
 $ Age                      : num  21 33 34 42 33 26 41 41 28 28 ...
 $ relevant_pos             : num  23238 100000 300000 165893 89366 ...
 $ crif_active_accounts     : num  0 10 11 18 9 0 11 13 0 0 ...
 $ crif_overdue_amt         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ crif_current_outstanding : num  0 3696499 8722449 519849 115283 ...
 $ cibil_active_accounts    : num  0 10 12 0 0 0 12 0 0 0 ...
 $ cibil_overdue_amt        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ cibil_current_outstanding: num  0 3738994 8738488 0 0 ...
 $ NACH.status              : Factor w/ 6 levels "active","nach-registration-initiated",..: 4 1 1 4 1 1 4 1 4 4 ...
 $ Tenure.End               : Factor w/ 4 levels "Closed","No",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ LastMonthBnc             : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ Last.Month.delinq        : Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ CIBIL.Bracket            : Factor w/ 10 levels "-1","490-600",..: 10 4 6 10 1 5 10 5 10 10 ...
 $ Salary.Bracket           : Factor w/ 10 levels "125K-200K","30k-40k",..: 9 5 7 4 6 2 1 1 5 9 ...
 $ DELINQ.NON.DELINQ        : Factor w/ 2 levels "DELINQ","NON DELINQ": 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Month                    : num  9 9 10 6 9 10 6 10 10 6 ...
 $ state                    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...`
```

Above i have converted the data(train-test into matrix format(as it is must for xgboost().

```
library("Matrix")
sparse_matrix <- sparse.model.matrix(state ~ ., data = smoted_data)
deliq_sept_mat<-sparse.model.matrix(state ~ ., data = deliq_sept)
#deliq_oct_mat<-sparse.model.matrix(state ~ ., data = deliq_oct)
smoted_data_mat_label<-as.matrix(as.numeric(smoted_data$state))
smoted_data_mat_label = smoted_data[,"state"] == 1

xgb.fit <- xgboost(
  data = sparse_matrix,
  label = smoted_data_mat_label,
  eta = 0.01,#this is like shrinkage in the previous algorithm
  max_depth = 3,#Larger the depth, more complex the model; higher chances of overfitting. There is no standard                      value for max_depth. Larger data sets require deep trees to learn the rules from data.
  min_child_weight = 3,#it blocks the potential feature interactions to prevent overfitting
  nrounds = 10000,#controls the maximum number of iterations. For classification, it is similar to the number of                       trees to grow.
  nfold = 5,
  objective = "binary:logistic",  # for regression models
  verbose = 0,               # silent,
  early_stopping_rounds = 10 # stop if no improvement for 10 consecutive trees
)

deliq_sept$xgb.pred.class <- predict(xgb.fit, deliq_sept_mat)
```

When i am trying to optimize the algorithm with different values, output is not very intuitive to me. 
Below are the match of actual and predicted class outputs(predicted class 1 = 203 and actual are also 203).

```
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
    [1,]  203  203  203  203  203

for nrounds = 2, 50, 100, 1000, 10000

    221,199,203,206,189,178 
for max_depth = 1,3,5,7,9,15
```

And

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]  221  221  221  221  221  221    2
for eta = 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 1
```

So by Max depth what i could understand that algorithm was easily able to discriminate the classes in initial splits(and so need not to go for high depth) but not sure why with increase in depth correct predictions are going down.

Predicted probabilities for 2 classes are also pretty close.

```
table(xgb.pred.class)

xgb.pred.class
0.495001137256622 0.495651245117188 0.496811062097549 0.503574728965759 
             9582               875                41               415
```

One point to note that on same dataset i tried GLM(), NB() and KNN() for all identification of minority class(like 221 in above case) was extremely poor(could identify only 4-5% of cases correctly for minority class) however with xgboost() it was able to identify almost 85-90% cases correctly(not sure why it is performing so good than others).

I want to be sure that i am not making any mistake(or missing some hidden indications by data).

Comment: What is exactly class balance in your set?

Comment: Is the 85%-90% accuracy on the training set or on a separate validation set?

Comment: 85-90% accuracy(not overall its prediction of minority class, overall is good for all models for majority class prediction). The minority class prediction accuracy was seen on unseen data(not used for model training).

Comment: Class balance(after smote).  
> table(smoted_data$state)
    0     1 
21984  2061